# Printing an int value obtained from user

Tags: c, printing, int, scanf

The problem is at the `age` part, the compiler does not give me any errors but when I run it it prints a `random number` for int `age`

```
printf("Enter your name:");
scanf(" %s",&name1);
int age;
printf("\n\nHow old are you?");
scanf(" %d",&age);
char gender;
printf("\n\nEnter your gender[Male/Female]:");
scanf(" %s",&gender);
char confirmation;
printf("Confirmation: Your name is %s , you are %d years old , and you are a %s.\n\nAnswer[Y/N]:",&name1,age,&gender);
```

Comment: Are you preceding your inputted age with a space?

Comment: Also, what's the return value?

Comment: I'll bet if you initialise `int age=42`; the output won't be as random as you thought.

Comment: @WeatherVane The user is supposed to imput the age and not me -_-

Comment: Using `&` with `%s` is a mistake

Comment: @AlucardVP22 my point was that by using an initialised variable, you would see that the output *isn't* random, but a failure to assign a new value to the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your problem.

```
char gender;
scanf(" %s",&gender);
```

`gender` is a `char`. That is, it only has memory for a 1 byte character. But you are using it as a string. You probably have the same problem for `name1` since you are using `&` for that as well but can't be sure as you don't show that.

Change that to be something like:

```
char gender[8] // Enough to fit "Female" and terminating NULL
scanf("%7s", gender);
```

Extra note: `scanf` is a bit awkward to use to prevent buffer safety. May consider something like `fgets` with `sscanf` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is also dynamic allocation, where you now do not have to specify the amount of storage to use.  Using the length modifier `%m` with the string type modifier `s`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *name = NULL
    char *gender = NULL;
    int age;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%ms", &name);

    printf("\nHow old are you? ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    printf("\nEnter gender: ");
    scanf(" %ms", &gender);

    printf("\n%s %d %s\n", name, age, gender);

    free(name);   //  free the memory
    free(gender); //   

    return 0;
}
```

In the last couple of lines you will notice a several calls to `free`.  This is because you are left with the responsiblility to free the memory allocated by `scanf`.

As pointed out by @Matt McNabb if you are on a non-posix compliant system, this will not work.  You can use `a` in place of `m`, while including  `#define _GNU_SOURCE` on the first line.

Comment: Good information! For completeness probably should check the return values of the `scanf` calls so that `free` can be done only if the `scanf` succeeds without error. Or initialise the pointers to NULL so that `free` always gets valid input (`NULL` is handled correctly by `free`).

Comment: Good point, I was thinking to make a comment about the safety checks not being there.

Comment: `%ms` is a POSIX extension, it's not in ISO C

Comment: @MattMcNabb I made note of this